# How to replace the following character contained in a perl variable?

Tags: perl

Hello I need to customize a perl script that is used to generate reports,

First it uses a variable called report to write a csv as follows:

```
open report ,">report";
```

Then this script perform a while, inside the while code just uses

```
print report $tpISAAddress."\n";
```

to write every line of the script and it generates the following output:

```
$ cat report
ZZ:BCGROUP
ZZ:ABGROS
ZZ:AGROUP
13808610
```

I would like to obtain instead this output, with two columns, the separator is ":", as follows:

```
ZZ,BCGROUP
ZZ,ABGROS
ZZ,AGROUP
13808610
```

The only thing that I wish is to replace ":" to ",", the problem is that I am not sure how to achieve this since I am more familiar with bash, in bash you could do this inside the while:

```
tpISAAddress=$(echo $tpISAAddress | sed s/:/,/g)
```

to replace this character, however I am not sure the process in perl to achieve this, I would like to appreciate support,

Comment: Add `$tpISAAddress =~ s/:/,/g;` before your `print`.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
$tpISAAddress =~ s/:/,/;
print report $tpISAAddress."\n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support, this was very useful.